# NGINX reverse proxy not loading all resources when location is defined

Tags: nginx, configuration, resources, loading, reverse-proxy

A friend of mine has asked around but has not resolved his issue of which I have the exact same issue and figured to ask here (more heads a better than one).

Here's the situation...

We each have NGINX installed and running great as a reverse proxy server on Raspberry Pi 3's.
We both have services running on our main computer/server that we've successfully reversed proxy with locations.
We both have another device separate from the computer/server (Pi-Hole on a 2nd RPi) that we've also successfully reversed proxy with locations.
There is one service located on a separate device we cannot get to fully work with reverse proxy.  This separate device is a remote IP controlled power outlet.

Here is a snippet of the current conf file we've created

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name my.domain.com;

            location /firstService {
                                        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:xxxx;
                                        include         /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                    }

            location /secondService/ {
                                        rewrite         /secondService/(.*) /$1 break;
                                        proxy_bind      $server_addr;
                                        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:yyyy;
                                        include         /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                    }

            location /pi-hole/ {
                                        proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.AAA/admin/;
                                        include         /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                    }

#   Configuration below fully loads and works INTERNALLY ONLY (IP address in address bar reflects
#   the proxy_pass address while it tries to load the same local IP externally which obviously
#   does not work)                          

#           location /powerOutlet/ {
#                                       rewrite         /powerOutlet/(.*) /$1 break;
#                                       proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.BBB/index.asp/;
#                   }

#   Configuration below partially loads BOTH internally and externally to the network
#   (missing much text, images, and other resources like javascript)

#           location /powerOutlet/ {
#                                       rewrite         /powerOutlet/(.*) /$1 break;
#                                       proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.BBB/;  #without index.asp at end
#                   }

#   Configuration below completely loads internally and externally to the network and fully funtional
#   (however, location is at root / )

#           location / {
#                                       proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.BBB/;
#                   }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the service should look like when fully loaded and functional:
[Service Web Interface Fully Loaded and Functional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inL0c.png)

Here is a screenshot of what the service looks like both internally and externally when using the 2nd config from above code:
[Service Web Interface Partially Loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liM2G.png)

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can get this remote IP power outlet to properly load with a location defined?

Comment: Try adding it as a subdomain (separate server block). There is a good chance the missing resources are defined with absolute locations.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think I have that option as the domain is already a subdomain/host of the router's free built-in dynamic DNS service.  But you're stating using a subdomain is the only way to go for resources defined with absolute locations right? (I may have to look at domains by Google if that's the case)

Comment: Subdomains would be the easiest solution, but you could look into using having nginx rewrite the response with [HttpSubModule](http://serverfault.com/questions/336338/using-nginx-to-rewrite-urls-inside-outgoing-responses). This can be prone to failure, so getting a domain([dot.tk](http://dot.tk/) is free) and adding CNAME pointing to your dynamic domain would work better.

Comment: Thanks again!  Subdomains do seem the easiest solution...subdomains is the path I'll follow (the path of least resistance).